# after onClick() notification opens customactivity, I can't get back to mainactivity

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

In my app I have MainActivity and let's say another CustomActivity. Normally my app starts with mainActivity, that's ok.

But I am sending a firebase notifications, and what I want is to open CustomActivity after I click the notification.

I think I've managed this, because it works:

```
  if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , CustomActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

So when a notification is tapped, it will launch CustomActivity.

However, in my CustomActivity I have a back arrow on the top, and of course it will not work, because CustomActivity was my start activity and the app doesn't know where to return step back...

Please what to do with this? I want to bring the user back to MainActivity if he clicks the back arrow.

The arrow is working if the notification is tapped when the app is running, because the MainActivity lifecycle is still on, but the arrow works not when the app is closed and customActivity is iniciated as first.

Comment: If you redirecting to CustomActivity trough the code you posted from MainActivity you can simply DO NOT ```finish()``` so it get to the activity stack below CustomActivity and the back arrow would work as indeed

Comment: thank you! The removal of finish() worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you redirecting to CustomActivity trough the code you posted from the MainActivity, you can simply DO NOT `finish()` so it get to the activity stack below CustomActivity and the back arrow work as indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ParentActivity tag in Manifest like below -

```
<activity
        android:name=".CustomActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: seems like another great solution, but for now I just removed finish() from my code as Marcos suggested and it is working now. Thank you

Comment: @wotan No Problem :)

Comment: well, I've just noticed that my original code is not good. However it is working fine when a notification is tapped, but getIntent().getExtras() is also NOT NULL, when I launch the app from my phone! So it opens the CustomActivity also on the app start

Comment: @wotan use setAction on passed Intent, & check in Activity if the action you set is the same by intent.getAction().equals()... also do not set Default & Launcher Intent Filter to CustomActivity in manifest, if u are doing that

Comment: ah ok, I checked now Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras(); and if bundle.keySet() equals to "title" and it seems working fine

Comment: @wotan that's Good :)